Is the anomaly of Isaiah 7:10 explained by Jesus' words in John 12:49?
Isaiah 7:10-13

Again YHWH spoke to Ahaz: “Ask a sign of YHWH your God; let it be
deep as Sheol or high as heaven.” But Ahaz said, “I will not ask, and
I will not put YHWH to the test.” And Isaiah said, “Hear then, O
house of David! Is it too little for you to weary men, that you
weary my God also?

Notice that when Isaiah speaks to Ahaz in verse 10, it says "YHWH spoke to Ahaz", despite Isaiah being the person who speaks to Ahaz.
Is this an example of divine agency, where the instrument of God can speak on behalf of God as though he is God himself?
Do Jesus' words in John 12:49 validate this interesting notion?
John 12:49

"For I have not spoken from myself, but the Father himself who
sent me has commanded me what I should say and what I should
speak."

Matthew 20:10

"For it is not you who speak, but the Spirit of your Father speaking
through you."

2 Samuel 23:2-4

The Spirit of YHWH spoke through me; His word was on my tongue.
The God of Israel spoke; the Rock of Israel said to me,
‘He who rules the people with justice, who rules in the fear of God,
is like the light of the morning at sunrise of a cloudless dawn, the
glistening after the rain on the sprouting grass of the earth.’


In the reported incident in Isa 7 it is abundantly clear that Isaiah is reporting the words of God and NOT speaking on God's behalf.  I fail to see the point you are attempting to construct.  See V7.  The prophets always make this clear with, "This is what the LORD says ..." or similar.

Is this an example of divine agency, where the instrument of God can speak on behalf of God as though he is God himself?
Short Answer: Yes
Isaiah acts as God's messenger, and his words are directly attributed to God (YHWH spoke to Ahaz). This certainly fits the biblical pattern of divine agency that is scattered all throughout scripture.
Like God did with Moses:
Exodus 4:12-16

11 But the Lord said to him, “Who has made the human mouth? Or who
makes anyone unable to speak or deaf, or able to see or blind? Is it
not I, the Lord?
12 Now then go, and I Myself will be with your mouth, and instruct you
in what you are to say.” 13 But he said, “Please, Lord, now send the
message by whomever You will.” Aaron to Be Moses’ Mouthpiece
14 Then the anger of the Lord burned against Moses, and He said, “Is
there not your brother Aaron the Levite? I know that he speaks
fluently. And moreover, behold, he is coming out to meet you; when he
sees you, he will be overjoyed. 15 So you are to speak to him and
put the words in his mouth; and I Myself will be with your mouth and
his mouth, and I will instruct you in what you are to do. 16 He shall
speak for you to the people; and he will be as a mouth for you and you
will be as God to him.

Like God did with Balaam:
Numbers 22:38

38 So Balaam said to Balak, “Behold, I have come to you now! Am I
really able to speak anything? The word that God puts in my mouth,
that only shall I speak.”

Like with Jeremiah:
Jeremiah 1:9

9 Then the Lord stretched out His hand and touched my mouth, and the
Lord said to me,
“Behold, I have put My words in your mouth.

According to 2 Peter we know that prophecies are delivered by human prophets but are inspired by the Holy Spirit.
2 Peter 1:21

21 for no prophecy was ever made by an act of human will, but men
moved by the Holy Spirit spoke from God.

Based on this we may conclude that divine agency is fundamental to how God interacts with humanity through His chosen messengers.

Jason_ Then following this understanding, was the Angel of the Lord carrying out divine agency when speaking as God in the first person? Is the Angel worshipped because he has the divine Name within him as the representative of God?

This does not prove the point because all of these make it very clear that they are speaking the words given them by God.  You have fallen for the trap laid by this to allow the OP to claim that Jesus was not really God.

@Dottard It appears many edits have been made to the question from when I initially read the question so I see what you mean. I agree that these all are agents, using God's words, to communicate God's message. I think this aligns with the given definition of "the instrument of God can speak on behalf of God as though he is God himself". I might be convinced otherwise, but I believe that "speaking on behalf" can include God's actual words.

@Dottard As for Jesus, I don't subscribe to the idea that Jesus was not really God. However, I understand and will attain to respect people that have diverse beliefs and interpretations. That said, I think we must distinguish Jesus' words from the notion of mere prophetic agency that we see in other biblical figures. Jesus speaks with divine authority. Perhaps in a sense we might call Him "the perfect agent of the Father", that doesn't mean He is not simultaneously fully divine, as affirmed by various other scriptures throughout the New Testament.

@Jason_"That doesn't mean he is not simultaneously fully divine, as affirmed by various other scriptures throughout the New Testament." Mention one single verse where Jesus claims to be God himself!

Yes, the prophets often spoke in the first person, representing God. So I would not call this an anomaly. It was a normal practice for God to speak to people this way. Indeed, every time the words: "thus sayeth the Lord" or "oracle of the Lord" are uttered by a prophet, the message that follows is an example of this principle.
This applies to at least some Christian prophecy. John 12:49 indeed represents an form of this principle. However, in OT prophecy the prophet declares before the fact that the following specific words come from God, while in John 12, Jesus makes the claim about his teachings generally. Similarly in the case of Mt. 10, Jesus encourages the persecuted person not to worry about what to say, because God will inspire him or her. The words may be a defense or a testimony or, in some cases, a first-person prophecy. A good example of a testimony/defense a is Peter's speech in the Acts 5:

7 They brought them into their presence and questioned them, “By what
power or by what name have you done this?” 8 Then Peter, filled with
the holy Spirit, answered them, “Leaders of the people and elders: 9
If we are being examined today about a good deed done to a cripple,
namely, by what means he was saved, 10 then all of you and all the
people of Israel should know that it was in the name of Jesus Christ
the Nazorean whom you crucified, whom God raised from the dead; in his
name this man stands before you healed."

This speech fulfills the prediction that Christians would be inspired when speaking to their persecutors even though God did not deliver the message in the first person. I am not aware of any such first-person messages being recorded in the NT scripture.
Conclusion: It was normal for God to speak to through the prophets in the first person. However, this is not the only possible meaning of Mt. 10:20. God can inspire a person to speak in a certain way without necessarily speaking in the first person Godself. In the case of John 12:49, Jesus declares that his teachings in general come from God, while in OT prophecy, the prophet makes this claim about a specific declaration, followed by a first-person message from God.

DanFefferman – Then in Exodus 3, when the angel in the bush says in the first-person, "I am the God of...", would this not be God speaking through a particular angel who is his mediating agent or mouthpiece?

@OneGodOneLord the relationship of the Angel of the Lord to God himself is controversial and much discussed on this site. I am not prepared to give an answer in a brief comment.

DanFefferman – I understand that. But all I am asking is if the Angel of the Lord can be likened to Isaiah in the aspect of being an agent of God.
